# Infinite Scroll plugin scrolling truly "infinitely" (i.e. does not recognize end of posts)

Tags: plugins

I'm using the infinite scroll plugin and on some pages it just scrolls forever and is not showing the *"No more posts to load"* message.

Happens with newest WordPress version and also with the twentyeleven theme.

Anybody knows this problem?
How can I make this work?

Comment: Which plugin exactly? Had you tried contacting its developers? Can you provide URL to live example?

Comment: Any chance you are using wpml for translation and it only happens on pages that are in a non-primary language?

Comment: Yes, I have the wpml plugin installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I already had this problem some month ago.

It may help you to add the following code to your themes functions.php: http://pastebin.com/KbjS4ZeG

The problem in this case was actually located in a wp core function (redirect_canonical() in wp-includes/canonical.php) which tries to "repair" broken/malformed url's instead of showing an 404 error and ist not behaving in a constant way.

Comment: Quite the astonishing guess, that this must be a WPML conflict, given that the OP didn't mention it. The workaround you provide also appears solid. You'd surely have my upvote - *if it wasn't for the pastebin*. Please include code here instead of relying on an external (and possibly temporary) source.